# "Battery use" information screen not reporting apps

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, settings, battery

I've got a Samsung Galaxy S (international version) that I've just upgraded to Android 2.2 (Froyo) and now the battery usage page in settings (Settings => About phone => Battery use) only ever reports the following items: Display, Cell standby, Phone idle & Voice calls.

Although I upgraded only a couple of days after having the phone, I'm sure that it originally showed usage of other things like apps & live wallpaper... It's kind of useless how it is now, any ideas on how I get it displaying all usage again?

Comment: That does sound odd. Is there perhaps a threshold setting of some sort?

Comment: @AlEverett - That was what I thought at first, but even if I play a CPU intensive game for an hour or so, it doesn't register and if I dial *#*#4636#*#* I can see other things using CPU, etc that I would have thought would be enough...

Comment: I've noticed the same thing having switched from Eclair to Froyo on a Galaxy S as well. I thought it was intentional although it does seem like a downgrade in terms of features. Perhaps it ironically caused excessive battery use, so they removed it? Just speculating.

Answer (score 1):

Though I do not have an answer to your question - I suggest you check PowerTutor (at powertutor.org) and see if it helps in the interim and/or long term